# Super simple javascript function call

Tags: javascript, function

Super simple function:

```
function equals(a,b){return a==b;}
```

When I call it like this it works fine and returns true:

```
equals(1,1)
```

When I call it like this though it returns false, and I don't understand why:

```
equals.call(1,1)
```

I thought invoking function.call was the same as simply invoking the function. What am I missing here?

Comment: The first argument of call is context

Comment: Because you didn't pass the context - if you execute it in global scope then call it like this
`equals.call(this,1,1)`

Comment: When you refer to `this` in javascript, that is called the context. The first argument of `call` is to define what `this` is and then the functions arguments.

Comment: ohhhhhh, I think in the past I've only ever called function.call with 0 arguments, so I never realized it expected the context. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly why I prefer statically typed languages. These kind of errors are caught so much easier with type checking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument that `.call` expects is a value for `this` within that function invocation followed by the arguments you want to pass to the function.

Since your function contains no reference to `this`, you can get the result you want by passing `null` as the first argument:

```
equals.call(null, 1,1);
```

You can find further details about this method at the MDN docs [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Answer (score 2):

The first argument in [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is for the value that the function will treat as `this`. Since the function doesn't use `this`, you can just pass in anything you like, such as `null`:

```
equals.call(null, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

> The call() method calls a function with a given this value and
>   arguments provided individually.

The first parameter is the value of `this`:

```
function.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Since you pass there the value of 1 this is used as the `this`, which apparently is not correct. You should pass at the start the `null` and the the two numbers.

```
equals.call(null, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The first argument in when using `.call` is the reference for "this".

See this jsFiddle for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/4hfrc3sk/

Comment: Points for trying!

Answer (score 1):

The first argument for call should be `this`. Like this:

```
equals.call(this,1,1)
```

In your version it tried to compare one with undefined, because there was no third parameter provided.

Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 1):

The first argument of .call is context (= what "this" will refer too).

So you can do:

```
equals.call(undefined, 1, 1);
```

But it is rather pointless.

More reading about .call: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call

Answer (score 0):

If you want call to execute without specifying null or undefined as the first parameter, you could rewrite the code as follows:

```js
function equals(a,b) {
  var w = window;
  return (w.a == w.b);
}

d = document;
d.g = d.getElementById;

var a = 1;
var b = 1;
var res = equals.call(a,b);

d.g("answer").innerHTML= "\n<BR>" + a + " ==  " + b + "? " + res + "\n";

a = 5;
b = 9;
res = equals.call(a,b);

d.g("answer").innerHTML += "\n<BR>" + a + " ==  " + b + "? " + res;
```

```css
#answer {
font: 22pt Arial,Helvetica;
color: #090;
}
```

```html
<div id="answer"></div>
```

See [resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

However, if you want to simply provide a context of null or undefined in the function call, be sure that you leave out that argument in the function definition or an incorrect result may occur; see the [good](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjOgXE) and the [bad](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XgzQwW).